# Location Permission Dialog not showing up properly in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions

I have a location button in the ActionBar. On clicking that it will load up the given function `cityLocation()` .

The code executes as follows

1. When pressed for the first time it asks for location permission
2. If accepted it runs showCity() , else it pops up a Toast
3. If clicked again after rejecting, it executes the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` part (PS. I did not click Do not show again)

Anyway this was only the second time I had clicked the button and instead of asking me the location permission (with the do not show again checkbox) again, it executes the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` part.

I want the code to ask for location permission with the do not ask again checkbox, if the permission was rejected for the first time, and then if I reject it again (with the checkbox) and then click the actionbar item, then it should run the the `MaterialDialog.Builder` code.

Here's the code I'm having right now :

```
private void cityLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(WeatherActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WeatherActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                MaterialDialog dialog;
                MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.title("Permission needed")
                        .content("This Action Requires the Location Setting to be enabled. Go to Settings and check the Location Permission inside the Permissions View")
                        .positiveText("SETTINGS")
                        .negativeText("CANCEL")
                        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                final Intent i = new Intent();
                                i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        })
                        .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dialog = builder.build();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        READ_COARSE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            showCity();
        }
    }
    else {
        showCity();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == READ_COARSE_LOCATION
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        showCity();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Denied Location Permission" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the Full runtime permisssion check code:

```
 private void cityLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, READ_COARSE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            showCity();
        }
    } else {
        showCity();
    }
}

private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case READ_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showCity();

            } else {
                permission_denied();
            }
            break;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

public void permission_denied() {
    // permission was not granted
    //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
    // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
    //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WeatherActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
        showDialogOK("Permission is required for register",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                showCity();
                                break;
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
    } //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
    //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to settings and enable External storage permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showMaterialDialog();
    }
}

public void showMaterialDialog() {
    MaterialDialog dialog;
    MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.title("Permission needed")
            .content("This Action Requires the Location Setting to be enabled. Go to Settings and check the Location Permission inside the Permissions View")
            .positiveText("SETTINGS")
            .negativeText("CANCEL")
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    final Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            })
            .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    dialog = builder.build();
    dialog.show();

}

private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

1. it will show a dialog if user denies the permission ...
2. if user also check never ask again it will show the material dialog ..
3. If user grant the permission it will perform the required function..

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected the checkbox `neverAskAgain` in the permission Dialog, then

```
ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()
```

method will return false. so your logic of again showing a material dialog will not work if you keep it inside the if block.

if you have to show it again, do it in the else block.

Comment: Sir, I tried this but it gives me an infinite loop of the permission dialog and when I click on dont ask again, it then launches the material dialog..